# My javascript countdown clock is not stopping at 0

Tags: javascript, html

I am not a javasript and html expert.  i copied a countdown clock code from a site. the problem is it won't stop at 0 0 0 0, continue to counting backwords (minus values). How to stop this function. also how to insert this code in to this forum? Stackoverflow says me that my code is not properly formatted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="ven, 31 mar 2017 14:29:07 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title></title>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
body{ 
    font: normal 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;
    color: #eee;
    background: #353535;
}
#countdown{
    width: 465px;
    height: 112px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #222;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 24px 0;
    position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

#countdown:before{
    content:"";
    width: 8px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #444;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px; left: -10px;
}

#countdown:after{
    content:"";
    width: 8px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #444;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px; right: -10px;
}

#countdown #tiles{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#countdown #tiles > span{
    width: 92px;
    max-width: 92px;
    font: bold 48px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #111;
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin: 0 7px;
    padding: 18px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#countdown #tiles > span:before{
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: 13px;
    background: #111;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41%; left: -3px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#countdown #tiles > span:after{
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%; left: 0;
}

#countdown .labels{
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
}

#countdown .labels li{
    width: 102px;
    font: bold 15px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #f47321;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>



</head>
  <body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="countdown">
  <div id='tiles'></div>
  <div class="labels">
    <li>Days</li>
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Mins</li>
    <li>Secs</li>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>

var target_date = new Date("May 10 2017").getTime() + (3600*24); // set the countdown date
var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units

var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element

getCountdown();

setInterval(function () { getCountdown(); }, 1000);

function getCountdown(){

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    days = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) );
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 3600) );
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 60) );
    seconds = pad( parseInt( seconds_left % 60 ) );

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>"; 
}

function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i paste my code on this comment area and pressed Ctrl+K, it won't let me insert more charactors in the area "add comment". what can i do?

Comment: Don't insert it in the comment area. You want to edit your post, and in the menubar for the text area for your question, you'll see a button that shows 'code' when you mouse over it. Click that, and use IT to post your code.

Comment: Ok i did, thanks for the help so for, now you can help me with code.

Answer (score 0):

All this needs is an if statement before the *countdown.innerHTML* line to catch any minus values. Something like:

```
if((days < 0)||(minutes < 0)||(seconds < 0 )||(hours < 0)){
     days = 0;
     minutes = 0;
     hours = 0;
     days = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to store a reference to your countdown timer, then use clearInterval() to stop the timer when you hit your target. For the purposes of demonstration, I've changed your timer to ten seconds.

And thanks, Shilly -- much cleaner with your solution.

```js
// var target_date = new Date("May 10 2017").getTime() + (3600 * 24); // set the countdown date

//A dummy function with which to test.
var stopBy = new Date();
stopBy.setSeconds(stopBy.getSeconds() + 10);
var target_date = stopBy.getTime();

var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
var current_date;

var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element

getCountdown.timer = setInterval(getCountdown, 1000);

function getCountdown() {
  this.timer = null;
  // Check if we've hit!
  // Check to see if we've hit the target!
  if (current_date >= target_date) {
    clearInterval(getCountdown.timer);
  }
  // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
  current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

  if (seconds_left > 0) {

    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

  } else {
    days = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
    days = 0;
  }

  // format countdown string + set tag value
  countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + pad(days) + "</span><span>" + pad(hours) + "</span><span>" + pad(minutes) + "</span><span>" + pad(seconds) + "</span>";


}

function pad(n) {
  return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #eee;
  background: #353535;
}

#countdown {
  width: 465px;
  height: 112px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #222;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 24px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#countdown:before {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 65px;
  background: #444;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: -10px;
}

#countdown:after {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 65px;
  background: #444;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: -10px;
}

#countdown #tiles {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#countdown #tiles>span {
  width: 92px;
  max-width: 92px;
  font: bold 48px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #111;
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin: 0 7px;
  padding: 18px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#countdown #tiles>span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 13px;
  background: #111;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41%;
  left: -3px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#countdown #tiles>span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left: 0;
}

#countdown .labels {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
}

#countdown .labels li {
  width: 102px;
  font: bold 15px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #f47321;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="countdown">
        <div id='tiles'></div>
        <div class="labels">
          <li>Days</li>
          <li>Hours</li>
          <li>Mins</li>
          <li>Secs</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Used the other answer's tip for if the numbers go below zero, the setInterval timer is randomly not quite right...

Comment: Ok it stops after 10 seconds. then how can i set my deadline to stop in this code?

Comment: take a look at the first five lines. I commented out YOUR timer, and substituted my own. Simply delete the three code lines below yours, uncomment your timer, and you should be rolling.

Comment: It sufficed to check `if (seconds_left < 0)` above the days calculation, since you'll only get negative days once you pass the target date.

Comment: Dear Snowmonkey, it stops at the time, but it will counting backwards in background. whn i refresh the webpage, it gives me the counted value to the moment. eg: if i refresh the page after 10 secs, it shows me -10 secs and if i refresh after another 10 secs, it shows me -20 secs.

Comment: Are you setting your time as an absolute or relative. I mean, are you saying a firm time in HH:MM:SS or are you saying current time plus some interval?